# vowpal_wabbit training data

Tags: svm, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to understand vowpal_wabbit data structure for the training and test data but cannot seem to understand them.

I have some training data like.

Feature 1: 0 
Feature 2: 1
Feature 3: 10
Feature 4: 5
Class label : A

Feature 1: 0 
Feature 2: 2
Feature 3: 30
Feature 4: 8
Class label : C

Feature 1: 2 
Feature 2: 10
Feature 3: 9
Feature 4: 7
Class label : B

I have explored some training data examples based on this website.

http://hunch.net/~vw/validate.html

My Validation data

```
1 | haha:1 hehe:2 hoho:3
1 | haha:2 hehe:2 hoho:3 
3 | haha:3 hehe:2 hoho:3 
1 | haha:4 hehe:2 hoho:3 
2 | haha:5 hehe:2 hoho:3
```

However, I do not understand why it claims that I have 4 and 5 features respectively.

**Validation:**

Validation Feedback

```
Total of 5 examples pasted.

(example #1) Example “1 | haha:1 hehe:2 hoho:3”.
(example #1) Found “[label] |…” prefix format.
(example #1) Example label / response / class is “1”.
(example #1) Example has default “1.0” importance weight.
(example #1) Example has default “0” base.
(example #1, namespace #1) Using default namespace.
(example #1, namespace #1) Found 3 feature(s).
(example #1, namespace #1, feature #1) Label “haha”.
(example #1, namespace #1, feature #1) Value “1”.
(example #1, namespace #1, feature #2) Label “hehe”.
(example #1, namespace #1, feature #2) Value “2”.
(example #1, namespace #1, feature #3) Label “hoho”.
(example #1, namespace #1, feature #3) Value “3”.

(example #2) Example “1 | haha:2 hehe:2 hoho:3 ”.
(example #2) Found “[label] |…” prefix format.
(example #2) Example label / response / class is “1”.
(example #2) Example has default “1.0” importance weight.
(example #2) Example has default “0” base.
(example #2, namespace #1) Using default namespace.
(example #2, namespace #1) Found 4 feature(s).
(example #2, namespace #1, feature #1) Label “haha”.
(example #2, namespace #1, feature #1) Value “2”.
(example #2, namespace #1, feature #2) Label “hehe”.
(example #2, namespace #1, feature #2) Value “2”.
(example #2, namespace #1, feature #3) Label “hoho”.
(example #2, namespace #1, feature #3) Value “3”.
(example #2, namespace #1, feature #4) Label “”.
(example #2, namespace #1, feature #4) Using default value of “1” for feature.

(example #3) Example “3 | haha:3 hehe:2 hoho:3 ”.
(example #3) Found “[label] |…” prefix format.
(example #3) Example label / response / class is “3”.
(example #3) Example has default “1.0” importance weight.
(example #3) Example has default “0” base.
(example #3, namespace #1) Using default namespace.
(example #3, namespace #1) Found 4 feature(s).
(example #3, namespace #1, feature #1) Label “haha”.
(example #3, namespace #1, feature #1) Value “3”.
(example #3, namespace #1, feature #2) Label “hehe”.
(example #3, namespace #1, feature #2) Value “2”.
(example #3, namespace #1, feature #3) Label “hoho”.
(example #3, namespace #1, feature #3) Value “3”.
(example #3, namespace #1, feature #4) Label “”.
(example #3, namespace #1, feature #4) Using default value of “1” for feature.

(example #4) Example “1 | haha:4 hehe:2 hoho:3 ”.
(example #4) Found “[label] |…” prefix format.
(example #4) Example label / response / class is “1”.
(example #4) Example has default “1.0” importance weight.
(example #4) Example has default “0” base.
(example #4, namespace #1) Using default namespace.
(example #4, namespace #1) Found 4 feature(s).
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #1) Label “haha”.
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #1) Value “4”.
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #2) Label “hehe”.
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #2) Value “2”.
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #3) Label “hoho”.
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #3) Value “3”.
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #4) Label “”.
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #4) Using default value of “1” for feature.

(example #5) Example “2 | haha:5 hehe:2 hoho:3 ”.
(example #5) Found “[label] |…” prefix format.
(example #5) Example label / response / class is “2”.
(example #5) Example has default “1.0” importance weight.
(example #5) Example has default “0” base.
(example #5, namespace #1) Using default namespace.
(example #5, namespace #1) Found 5 feature(s).
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #1) Label “haha”.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #1) Value “5”.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #2) Label “hehe”.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #2) Value “2”.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #3) Label “hoho”.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #3) Value “3”.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #4) Label “”.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #4) Using default value of “1” for feature.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #5) Label “”.
(example #5, namespace #1, feature #5) Using default value of “1” for feature.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why it claims that i have 4 and 5 features respectively

The extra space symbols at the end of lines are interpreted as extra features by http://hunch.net/~vw/validate.html. (Yes, the last line in your sample has two extra spaces.) Note that validate.html reports an empty name of the extra features:

```
(example #4, namespace #1, feature #4) Label “”.
```

Note that [validate.html](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-validate.html) is implemented in JavaScript and is completely independent on the implementation of VW itself (which is in C). VW ignores the trailing spaces. You can test it with:

```
$ vw -P 1 < sample.data
...   
average    since         example     example  current  current  current
loss       last          counter      weight    label  predict features
1.000000   1.000000          1      1.0     1.0000   0.0000        4
0.522042   0.044084          2      2.0     1.0000   0.7900        4
1.838150   4.470366          3      3.0     3.0000   0.8857        4
1.488676   0.440255          4      4.0     1.0000   1.6635        4
1.270585   0.398217          5      5.0     2.0000   1.3690        4
```

So all five example are reported as having 4 features (see the last column).
Why four? There is an extra constant (intercept) feature automatically added. If you don't want it, you can use `vw --noconstant`.

Comment: +1 thanks Martin.  Yes, generally one should only rely on `vw` itself for accurate parsing of examples. `validate.html` was written as an aid by Ben, in order to help beginners, but it may not be maintained or checked frequently for incompatibilities, especially on new reductions, and other new `vw` features that keep being added at a pretty rapid pace lately.  The trailing spaces issue is a bug in the current `validate.html`